# What's the difference between `std::basic_string` and `std::__1::basic_string`?

Tags: c++, g++, libc++, ninja

`ninja` (version: 1.9.0) output:

```
mergetree_test.cpp:(.text+0x19f): undefined reference to `DB::executeQuery(std::string const&, DB::Context&, bool, DB::QueryProcessingStage::Enum, bool)'
```

`nm -A mergetree_test.o | grep executeQuery | c++filt` output:

```
mergetree_test.o:                 U DB::executeQuery(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, DB::Context&, bool, DB::QueryProcessingStage::Enum, bool)
```

But I got output from linked libaries where `executeQuery` defined using the same method.

```
libdbms.a:executeQuery.cpp.o:0000000000008750 T DB::executeQuery(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, DB::Context&, bool, DB::QueryProcessingStage::Enum, bool)
```

What does `__1` mean ? how can I solve the problem ?

Comment: Which compiler, and which version?

Comment: g++ (GCC) 10.2.0

Answer (score 5):

I suspect that you're attempting to combine libraries that were compiled using libc++ and libstdc++.

libc++ puts (almost) all of it's symbols into `std::_1::`, while libstdc++ puts it's symbols in `std::`

Answer (score 0):

You asked two questions so I'm gonna answer the main one(What is `__1`?):

`__1` is an inline namespace located in `std`:

```
namespace std
{
    inline namespace __1
    {
        // string, ...
    }
}
```

The `inline` means that one does not have to specify that the structure/function/variable is located in that namespace, so that one can simply use `std::string` instead of `std::__1::string`.

As for why you are getting errors: We can't know without you providing us with some code.

Comment: Why did symbols in `mergetree_test.o` without `__1`，but the libary I depended has? This maybe the problem.